# OpenGLES2.0 GL_POINT_SMOOTH

Tags: opengl-es

I'm using this code in a fragment shader to round the edges of a GL point

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 fragColor;

void main() {

    gl_FragColor = fragColor;

    if(length(gl_PointCoord-vec2(0.5)) > 0.5)
    discard;

}
```

The problem is, the rounding is applied to every type of primitive drawn in the context, including triangle strips.  Is there a way of adding an if statement to limit the rounding to only GL_POINTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just use a new shader for other primitives.

Two minor comments:

- Did you consider using a small texture (containing a circle) instead of doing a calculation like this? It might be a bit faster but it obviously depends on the details.
- Also try to avoid using the discard keyword. It might have a negative impact on performance. You could for example set the alpha value to 0 for those fragments that you currently discard.